# awk/sed: How to perform nested replace operation with two files?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace

I'm a complete newbie to bash operations. I have two files, lets call them file A and file B.

In file A I have a line like this:

```
STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED = "SOME_STRING_IN_FILE_A"
```

In file B I also have a similar line where just the string differs, like this:

```
STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED = "SOME_STRING_IN_FILE_B"
```

What I need to do is to find the lines that start with `STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED` in both files and replace the corresponding line in file B with the corresponding line in A.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to do this in a single command?

Comment: What output are you expecting? Do you want to permanently change file B?

Comment: Do you have multiple lines like this in both the files?

Comment: There is exactly one line like this in both files. @choroba

Comment: Yes, I want to permanently change the file B. @123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't have any special chars, perhaps two step `sed` is easier

```
key='STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED *= *';          \
val=$(sed 's/'"$key"'//' fileA);           \
sed -r 's/('"$key"').*/\1'"$val"'/' fileB

STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED = "SOME_STRING_IN_FILE_A"
```

you can make second `sed` replacement in place by adding `-i` option.

Comment: @anubhava's answer does the job in a single command but yours is more intuitive I think! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you can do this. This will scan fileA first by scanning first file for given search string and then using it to replace value in fileB.

```
awk -v s='STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED' 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=" = " } FNR == NR && $1 == s {
a[$1] = $2; next } $1 in a { $2 = a[$1] } 1' fileA fileB
```

To save changes into `fileB` use:

```
awk -v s='STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED' 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=" = " } FNR == NR && $1 == s {
a[$1] = $2; next } $1 in a { $2 = a[$1] } 1' fileA fileB > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp fileB
```

Comment: Lol what, you never even use the variable.

Comment: Lol :) intended to use but somehow forgot, it is fixed now

Answer (score 1):

1- Store the line in variable lineA

```
lineA=$(perl -ne 'if(/^\QSTRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED\E/){print;exit}' fileA)
```

2- Replace line in fileB, old file saved as .BAK

```
perl -i.BAK -pe 'BEGIN{$line=shift@ARGV}if(/^\QSTRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED\E/){$_="$line\n"}' "$lineA" fileB
```

or create new file: fileB.new without changing fileB

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$line=shift@ARGV}if(/^\QSTRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED\E/){$_="$line\n"}' "$lineA" fileB > fileB.new
```